# How to delete cookie MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I try to delete a cookie of my Node API in my Angular client (MEAN stack) but it doesn't work.

I have on Node side a controller and a router, and on my Angular I subscribe the service.

**// router node**

```
authRouter.get('/logout', this.passport.authenticate('jwt', {
  session: false
}), (req, res) => {
  logout()
    .then(apiResponse => sendApiSuccessResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.success, apiResponse))
    .catch(apiResponse => sendApiErrorResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.error, apiResponse));
});
```

**// controller node**

```
const logout = (res) => {
  res.cookie(process.env.COOKIE_NAME, '', {
    maxAge: -1,
    httpOnly: true
  });
};
```

**// service angular**

```
public logout(): Observable < any > {
  // GET '/auth/logout'
  console.log('logout service ok');
  return this.HttpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/logout`)
}
```

**// component angular call logout**

```
public logout = () => {
  return this.AuthService.logout()
};

ngOnInit() {
  this.logout();
};
```

Do you think the code is OK ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `cookies.set('process.env.COOKIE_NAME', {maxAge: Date.now()});`

Answer (score 0):

```
maxAge: 0
```

Setting to 0 means delete this cookie right now.